# What way (if any) can I get the reference to anonymous function's closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Let us consider the workable code:

```
var storage = {};

(function() {
    function internalMethod1() { ...; return; }
    function internalMethod2() { ...; return; }
    storage.storedMethod = internalMethod1;
})();

storage.storedMethod();
```

Is there any way to call `internalMethod2`, if it is not called in `internalMethod1`? In other words, can I access an anonymous closure from outside, if I have access only to one of its functions?

Comment: Can you just check inside the anonymouse function if method1 was called and call method2 if not or is this not in line with your needs?

Comment: `return internalMethod2` from IIFE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I access an anonymous closure from outside?

No. Scopes are private in JS, and there's absolutely no way to access them from the outside (unless you use the engine's implementation-specific debugging API…).

Variables (including functions) are only available in the same scope and its children. If you want to access their values outside of the scope, you're at the mercy of the function to expose them in some way (`return`, assign to global `storage` variable etc).

Comment: _"If you want to access them outside of the scope, you're at the mercy of the function to expose their values in some way (return"_ How is this answer different from solution below , where `return` is used to return `internalMethod2` from IIFE ? Did Bergi "downvote" answer by this user below ? If yes, reason for "downvote" ?

Comment: @guest271314: Your answer does show one way to expose the function, yes. No, I did not downvote it, why do you think so?

Comment: Did not accuse, nor even "think so" ; only asked. When no description left at comment , not aware of what was lacking in provided answer? Although providing "description" for "downvote" not required at SO as per meta Questions/Answers, at least here , would prefer to be aware of reason for "downvote" to , if possibly improve , correct issue with provided answer; improve awareness of `js` . Difficult to improve post if reason for "downvote" not provided

Comment: Have a great day! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your discussion, fellows.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access a private, unreferenced scope after it has been executed. You would need to create another closure to create a reference to whatever private method you wanted to expose.

```
var storage = {};

(function() {
    function internalMethod1() { 
        return {
            internalPublic1: internalMethod2
        };
    }

    function internalMethod2() {  
        console.log('hi');
    }

    storage.storedMethod = internalMethod1;
})();

var a = storage.storedMethod();
a.internalPublic1(); //'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining IIFE as variable , return reference to `internalMethod2` from IIFE

```js
var storage = {};

var method2 = (function() {
    function internalMethod1() { console.log(1) };
    function internalMethod2() { console.log(2) };
    storage.storedMethod = internalMethod1;
    return internalMethod2
})();

storage.storedMethod();

method2();
```